# Blank upload window after update to 2.6

Tags: ee2

Just upgraded to 2.6 and know my file upload window comes up blank. There’s no errors and everything seems in order. Currently at a loss on how to trouble shoot it.

Basically, when you click the “upload file” button in file manager it comes up blank

Here’s a screen shot from trying to edit or add new content:
http://cl.ly/image/433j413a2F2q

Here’s how it looks if i were to just go to content > files > file manager and try to upload from there:

http://cl.ly/image/1c151v2Q2U0Y

Really stuck on this one.

Thanks,
Jamie

Comment: Ok, this ended up being really simple.

Apparently the themes folder got corrupted or goofed up when upgrading. Dumped and re-uploaded and now it's fine and dandy.